# Invoke Postgres Stored Procedure with User Defined Type list parameter using Dapper and Npgsql 7.0.0+

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, stored-procedures, dapper, npgsql

I want to call a stored procedure in a Postgres DB by passing a user defined type parameter and I want to use Dapper and npgsql latest stable version which is 7.0.

I was able to implement this using npgsql version 6.0.0 with this code:

```
// Register the composite type mapper
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapComposite<CustomerType>("customer_type");

var connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=test;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=testDB;Pooling=true;";

using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);

con.Open();

// Call the insert_customer_list stored procedure
var customers = new[]
                {
                    new CustomerType {Name = "John Doe", Email = "john.doe@example.com", Phone = "555-1234"},
                    new CustomerType {Name = "Jane Smith", Email = "jane.smith@example.com", Phone = "555-5678"}
                };

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

parameters.Add("cust_list", customers);

con.Execute("CALL insert_customer_list(@cust_list)", parameters);

Console.WriteLine("Stored procedure executed successfully.");
```

Even though I am able to make this code work with the upgraded version of npgsql (v7.0.0), the `GlobalTypeMapper.MapComposite` method is obsolete in this version.

The documentation mentions that

> NpgsqlDataSource was introduced in Npgsql 7.0, and is the recommended way to manage type mapping

However I couldn't find a proper documentation to make `NpgsqlDataSource` to use with Dapper.

One disadvantage of using npgsql version 6.0.0 is that I need to call a procedure and provide its parameter as shown in the above code (CALL insert_customer_list(@cust_list)), can this be avoided using npgsql version 7?

I had tried to make this work for version 7 with below code changes but its throwing error
**System.NotSupportedException: 'The CLR type DapperNpgsqlExample.CustomerType isn't natively supported by Npgsql or your PostgreSQL. To use it with a PostgreSQL composite you need to specify DataTypeName or to map it, please refer to the documentation.'**

Code Modified

```
// Register the composite type mapper
                ////NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapComposite<CustomerType>("customer_type");

                var connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=test;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=testDB;Pooling=true;";
                var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
                dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<CustomerType>("customer_type");
                using var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
 

                using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();

 

                // Call the insert_customer_list stored procedure
                var customers = new[]
                {
                    new CustomerType {Name = "John Doe", Email = "john.doe@example.com", Phone = "555-1234"},
                    new CustomerType {Name = "Jane Smith", Email = "jane.smith@example.com", Phone = "555-5678"}
                };
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("cust_list", customers);
                con.Execute("insert_customer_list", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

 

                Console.WriteLine("Stored procedure executed successfully.");
```

Comment: Maybe `con.Execute("insert_customer_list", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` not sure if that works in Npgsql but works in SqlClient for SQL Server.

Comment: @Charlieface con.Execute("insert_customer_list", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); even after updating this statement we get an exception as System.NotSupportedException: 'The CLR type DapperNpgsqlExample.CustomerType isn't natively supported by Npgsql or your PostgreSQL. To use it with a PostgreSQL composite you need to specify DataTypeName or to map it, please refer to the documentation.'

Comment: The answer there does not seem to work with NpqSql 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved with the help of this following post https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64812

Checkout the modified code as per this post.

```cs
var connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=test;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=testDB;Pooling=true;";
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<CustomerType>("customer_type");

using var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
    
using (var connection = dataSource.OpenConnection())
{
    // Use the connection as usual
    // Call the insert_customer_list stored procedure
    var customers = new[]
    {
        new CustomerType {Name = "John Doe", Email = "john.doe@example.com", Phone = "555-1234"},
        new CustomerType {Name = "Jane Smith", Email = "jane.smith@example.com", Phone = "555-5678"}
    };
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("cust_list", customers);
    connection.Execute("insert_customer_list", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Stored procedure executed successfully.");
}
```

Comment: An explanation of what you changed would be useful, the link is not enough by itself